# MySql SUM(), grouping by month, Months with '0' don't appear

Tags: mysql, date, group-by, sum

I have this MySql query:

```
SELECT YEAR(date), MONTHNAME(date), SUM(block_time)
FROM flights
WHERE operator = 'PSD'
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

The problem I am having is if a month has zero hours it doesn't appear in the results.  What do I need to change in order to see all months whether or not there is any time flown that month?

Comment: I call shenanigans. Is it perhaps that said months do not match the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @pst - I think that's the point - there are no flights that month for the `WHERE` clause but the month (& year) should still be included in the resultset, with 0 hours.

Comment: You could have a table of months and JOIN to it, I suppose. I'm not sure whether that's a good idea or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a table including all the years / months your want in your results, and would need to join it as below...

```
SELECT myMonths.theYear, myMonths.theMonth, COALESCE(theData.hours, 0)
FROM myMonths
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT YEAR(date) AS theYear, MONTHNAME(date) AS theMonth, SUM(block_time) AS hours
    FROM flights
    WHERE operator = 'PSD'
    GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTHNAME(date)
) theData
ON myMonths.theYear = theData.theYear
AND myMonths.theMonth = theData.theMonth
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Well, it absolutely could be my error but now I'm returning '0.0' for all months now.  Hey, atleast I have the '0' in the proper month. :)  Now I just need to get the block time back for the other months!  I'll keep fiddling with it.

Comment: @LazyB - you just need to ensure that your `myMonths` tables contains the year & month in the same format as your original query returns.

Answer (score 0):

try to union with those that have no hours

```
SELECT YEAR(date), MONTHNAME(date), SUM(block_time)
FROM flights
WHERE operator = 'PSD'
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)

UNION ALL 

SELECT YEAR(date), MONTHNAME(date), SUM(block_time)
FROM flights
WHERE hours = 0
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```